# Installed Elasticsearch 5.5 and failed to start the service

Tags: java, elasticsearch, centos

Installed elasticsearch v5.5 in centos and ran the following command to initiate the service.

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Getting following error while running the above command.

```
Starting elasticsearch: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000085330000, 2060255232, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2060255232 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid15359.log
```

Suggest me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch starts with 2 GB of RAM as default in 5.X versions.

Assuming that you are using virtual machine, it seems like your VM has less free memory than 2GB. Try giving your VM more memory or change your Elasticsearch JVM settings in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` (for example set `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`).